# Why can't Artifactory download requested artifact?

Tags: maven, maven-2, artifactory

We deploy to Artifactory an artifact that has a [filename] name that gets a time stamp applied to it by Artifactory. Later in a different trunk, its build attempts to download that artifact using the same name under which it got deployed earlier. However, because of the time stamp that Artifactory applied to the file name, this subsequent build fails with a "Unable to download the artifact from any repository" error. Other than turning of Artifactory time stamping, is there a solution to this problem? Our belief was that Artifactory would be smart enough to know at least to return the latest time stamped artifact when requested.

Comment: Is it a `SNAPSHOT` artifact (i.e. with a version `xxx-SNAPSHOT`) ?

Comment: Yup. It's definitely a snapshot scenario. The requester downloader running in a different build wants the latest snapshot but can't get it because it doesn't know the time stamp name.

Comment: I have similar issue with maven 3 and nexus repository. Did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Normally this would be a comment but since I'm lacking the rep for this I do this as answer:
For sure Artifactory should be able to handle this. Why do you think the timestamp is the problem? This is normal for snapshots and f.e. the maven-metadata.xml should indicate which is the last version.

Do you use a version range for the artifact?

> its build attempts to download that artifact using the same name under which it got deployed earlier.

Do I get you right: The artifact that you describe to be deployed to Artifactory in its (own) build wants to use itself? Could you post relevant parts of your POM?

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue recently after I changed repository configuration from storing non-unique snapshots to unique snapshots. (See [here](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories))

When both unique snapshot and non-unique snapshot of the same version of an artifact exists, there will be problem to download it.

For example, in a repository if under folder `/com/mycompany/test/foo/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/` there are `foo-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom` and `foo-1.0.0-20130329-231102-1.pom`, then downloading com.mycompany.test:foo:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:pom will get error. You have to delete either the file with SNAPSHOT in name or all the files with time stamp in name.

For my case, my repository switched from storing non-unique snapshots to unique snapshots, so I should delete the *-SNAPSHOT files. I wrote a Ruby script to scan all recent deployed artifacts and try to delete the same version non-unique snapshot (-SNAPSHOT) file if any. It uses Artifactory's REST API. Here is the source: https://gist.github.com/aleung/5260512